# short date in python (dd/mmm/yyyy)

Tags: python, time

I need to check a date by comparing it to today's date but the format I am originally given is `12 Dec 2016`.

I am not sure If I can even use pythons `time` modules to help me out with comparing it to the date of today because it is in a different format.

Comment: Looks like `%d %b %Y` to me.

Comment: That's *not* an unusual format.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is french date format [Date and time notation in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_France)

Comment: @ettanany: that format is [used far wider than just France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country). Wikipedia estimates it is used by 3.3 billion people... The *specific* format of dd mmm yyyy is especially prevalent in the US.

Comment: Sorry! you said "not an unusual" and I read it "not a usual".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date = datetime.strptime('12 Dec 2016', '%d %b %Y')
```

Now, you can compare `my_date` with `datetime.today()`

**Output:**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> my_date = datetime.strptime('12 Dec 2016', '%d %b %Y')
>>>
>>> my_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 12, 0, 0)
>>>
>>> my_date.date()
datetime.date(2016, 12, 12)
>>>
>>> datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 16, 9, 44, 21, 562000)
>>> 
>>> datetime.today().date()
datetime.date(2016, 12, 16)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the format before hand you can use this:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

print parser.parse("12 Dec 2016").date()
print datetime.now().date()
print parser.parse("12 Dec 2016").date() == datetime.now().date()
```

Output:

```
2016-12-12
2016-12-16
False
```